# How to customize embedded YouTube video players?

Tags: iframe, youtube

When you embed a YouTube video using its provided `<iframe>` code: you're not able to hide title and a couple other "features".

Some of these features could be disabled using parameters, back in a day. As of now: they're deprecated.

So, now I'm left with a client that needs to embed YouTube videos without all of that junk we see when hovering over the video: title, related videos, channel logo, etc.

Answer (score 4):

From what I've researched, it's not possible to disable title and a some other features: be it using URL parameters or CSS+JS.

Although, I've come with a solution that has a lot of potential: not only for user's privacy, but also for UX. **This solution is:**

1. figuring out a way to extract YouTube videos source URL;
2. using extracted URL in `<video>` or `<iframe>`;
3. replicate YouTube player styles.

For the first part, I've used Invidious API. But I think you can also create an API that uses `youtube-dl` to extract videos URL (?).

In my tests, I didn't even had to install my own isntance of Invidious: I've used public API endpoints:

`https://yewtu.be/latest_version?id=dasdsa312&itag=84`

Where:

- id: video ID;
- [itag](https://gist.github.com/sidneys/7095afe4da4ae58694d128b1034e01e2): video stream format code.

Then, I made JavaScript code to:

- dynamically get all available Invidious public instances;
- generate a video element with sources to many different video quality and available instances.

These sources are generated depending on the query parameters available in my website URL:

`https://riservato-xyz.frama.io/watch/?v=gprAWYQ47uY`

With that in mind, whenever I need a customized YouTube player, I can use my own website to embed YouTube videos.

I understand the testing website (former url) is slow, indeed. Although, this is because I'm not using my own Invidious instance and rely on public instance. BUT IT WORKS!

```html
<iframe width="560" 
        height="315" 
        src="https://riservato-xyz.frama.io/watch/?v=W_xIBfrdxQU" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: It seems sometimes it's not working. For example for this one: https://riservato-xyz.frama.io/watch/?v=rCdHk1eTe34 I'm getting 403/404 errors.